# String is displayed on every condition of if statement

Tags: php

I have this code where i wanted to display different values from my array; It is working fine but i can't seem to remove a string () i defined on my else statement.

```
 <?php 
 if ($row ['GPT'] == 'FALSE' && $row ['OPT'] == 'TRUE') 
 { echo $row ['OPT']; } 

 elseif ($row ['GPT'] == 'TRUE' && $row ['OPT'] == 'FALSE') 
 { echo $row ['GPT']; } 

 else 
 { echo $row ['GPT'] . ' ' . '(' . $row ['OPT'] . ')' ; } ?>
```

The statement will display this output:

GPT ()
OPT ()
GPT (OPT)

What should happen is:

GPT
OPT
GPT (OPT)

The parentheses on else shows on both if and elseif. My questions is that is there any way to display it without affecting the other statements?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: note: boolean is TRUE/FALSE not 'TRUE' / 'FALSE'

Comment: You nailed it, I did not know that it was just an apostrophe causing my problem.